# Как мне в приложение xamarin (android) передать/принять данные на сервер/бд MySql?

Tags: php, c#, mysql, база-данных, xamarin

Пишу приложение под android на **C# Xamarin**, и хочу передать какие-нибудь данные в базу данных Mysql.
Пытался сделать это через *Mysql connector, но Xamarin конфликтует с коннектором*.
В поисках решения нагуглил: HttpClient .net, REST-api, RestSharp, json...
Что надо как-то обработать данные на сервере через api, то ли php, то ли js...
И тут я поплыл окончательно.
Так вот, господа, помогите с реализацией - простенький примерчик того как принять и передать данные на клиенте и на сервере.

Comment: Что именно вам непонятно? Что конкретно у вас не получается? В интернете полно примеров по всем вашим вопросам. Чем вас они не устроили? Если вы там ничего не понимаете, то возможно, программирование не ваш конёк

Comment: [Xamarin Android App with online MySql/Sql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48383008/xamarin-android-app-with-online-mysql-sql-database)

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю ни ксамарина, ни андроида и готового примерчика не дам.
Правильно ли я понял, что вам нужно отправить данные на компьютер в локальной сети?

Если вы не можете подконнектится к серверу MySQL напрямую, то придется коннектится к какому то промежуточному приложению, которое передаст их на сервер.

Это может быть либо какой-нибудь скрипт php или asp на локальном веб-сервере. В таком случае вы посылаете туда post запрос, в скрипте его расшифровываете и вставляете в базу как хотите. Существуют некие методы оформления http запроса, которые преподносятся как великие открытия в технологии. Но по сути в каком уж виде вы свой запрос зашифруете - дело второстепенное. Хоть в своем собственном, а потом расшифруете его в скрипте.

Главное вам суметь
1) установить в локальной сети веб-сервер
2) передать туда из андроида http запрос.

Можно не связываться с вебсервером, а написать:
1. свое простенькое приложение для компьютера, которое по сокету принимает 
данные и выполняет sql-запросы к БД.
2. суметь с андроида по сокету подключаться к опредленному адресу в сети по определнному порту(которое занимает ваше серверное приложение) и отправлять туда данные.

По большому счету все эти красивые аббревиатуры, которые вы перечислили, сводятся к одному из этих двух методов - либо через веб-сервер, либо через сокет (или что то похожее) по локальной сети.

Для Дельфи XE 10 существуют стандартные компоненты DataSnap, которые облегчают создание клиентного и серверного приложения. Что есть в ксамарине - не знаю.

Надеюсь я немного помог туману в вашей голове развеяться.